# JAVA: syntax error insert else statement to complete if statement

Tags: java

Hi im making a plugin for my minecraft server but now i have a problem, im stuck with and if else statement while updating it. 
I have searched on a lot of forums but it didn't help so now im here.
I use eclipse.

```
        if(commandName.equals("t")){

        }
            if(!player.hasPermission("Clans.teamchat")) {
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You do not have permission to use this command.");
                return true;
            }
            if(!tPlayer.hasTeam()) {
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You are not on a team.");
                return true;
            }
            else if(!getRank(PlayerName).canTeamChat()) {
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You lack sufficient permissions to talk in team chat.");
                return true;
            }
            else if (args.length < 1) {
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You did not enter a message to send.");
                return true;
            }
            else if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("@loc")) {
            return true;
            }
```

Comment: the IDE you use is not relevant. but do you see why this is redundant: if(commandName.equals("t")){

        }? did you add a return statement after that last else if ? if not, there is no return for all possible cases

Comment: What/where is the syntax error you need help with?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it that's all the relevant code but could be that you are missing a final `return` statement after those `if`. The reason is that with your code as is now, you are not handling the case of not matching any of your conditions but you still need to provide a return value for your method.

Comment: In that case the error will be `missing return statement` but above error is totally different.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more diligent here; it starts with formatting and braces. You really want that each block after an if, even stuff like

```
if (something) {
   just one thing 
} else {
   just another thing
}
```

comes as block within { and }. And then you format your code in a disciplined way (you know, any decent IDE can do that for you) - in order to simply be able to grasp the "content" that you are creating.

In other words: your problem is simply that you are violating syntax rules. And the easiest way to avoid that - is by writing source code that carries a **structure** that guides you.

You see, probably you are missing a final return statement, or you put two elses after each other - all of that would become obvious, if you would just write down your code using the same rules and formatting constantly.

The other thing of course: such lengthy if/else chains are always something that you want to avoid by doing proper OO designs. You don't ask for object properties to then make decisions; instead you use interfaces, that come with different implementations; so, later on, you just call those methods ( see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc&index=4&list=PLD0011D00849E1B79) for a detailed explanation of that ).